# Kotlin to Java (Library Help)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using this library to generate gradients:
https://github.com/revely-inc/co.revely.gradient

The kotlin code to animate the gradient is as follows:

```
val color1 = Color.parseColor("#00c6ff")
val color2 = Color.parseColor("#ff72ff")

val valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 360f)
valueAnimator.duration = 15000
valueAnimator.repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
valueAnimator.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
RevelyGradient.sweep()
    .colors(intArrayOf(color1, color2, color1))
    .animate(valueAnimator, { _valueAnimator, _gradientDrawable ->
         _gradientDrawable.angle = _valueAnimator.animatedValue as Float
    })
    .onBackgroundOf(container)
valueAnimator.start()
```

The java code that I have attained until now:

```
ValueAnimator valueAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
                        valueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 360f);
                        valueAnimator.setDuration(15000);
                        valueAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
                        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                        RevelyGradient.sweep()
                                .colors(new int[] {Color.parseColor("#FF2525"), Color.parseColor("#6078EA")})
                                .animate(valueAnimator, { _valueAnimator, _gradientDrawable ->
                                        _gradientDrawable.angle = _valueAnimator.animatedValue as Float
                                })
                                .onBackgroundOf(rootView);
                        valueAnimator.start();
```

As you notice, I cannot convert this (since it doesn't make sense to a kotlin outsider):

```
{ _valueAnimator, _gradientDrawable ->
   _gradientDrawable.angle = _valueAnimator.animatedValue as Float
   }
```

What is supposed to be done here?

Error:

> required: 'kotlin.jvm.functions.Function2? super
>   android.animation.ValueAnimator,? super
>   co.revely.gradient.drawables.Gradient,kotlin.Unit>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an anonymous function (a "lambda expression"). It looks like `RevelyGradient.animate()` takes two arguments:

1. A [ValueAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html).
2. A function: one that takes a ValueAnimator and a [Gradient](https://github.com/revely-inc/co.revely.gradient/blob/d2009ccfd5d6a6105d063f105be9dd5efe9a0f7b/gradient/src/main/java/co/revely/gradient/drawables/Gradient.kt) as arguments and returns nothing useful. (It returns a [Unit](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/index.html).)

In the specific function you passed in, the Gradient's `angle` property is being set from the ValueAnimator's [animatedValue property](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#getAnimatedValue()) (which is cast to a [Float](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-float/index.html) before assignment).

So how do you rewrite this in Java? Since this is an Android question, you'll need to [enable Java 8 language features](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html) for the module you're working on. Then you should be able to rewrite that line of code to look something like this:

```
RevelyGradient
    .animate(valueAnimator,
            (_valueAnimator, _gradientDrawable) -> {
               _gradientDrawable.setAngle((Float) _valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
               return Unit.INSTANCE;
            });
```

Comment: It says: "Bad return type in lambda expression: void cannot be converted to Unit"

Comment: Try the edited version. ([Here's](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/java-interop-unit-closures-required-to-return-kotlin-unit/1842) a somewhat related discussion.)

Comment: Now it doesn't animate. (compiles fine)

Comment: Does it work when written in Kotlin? If not, that's a separate question.

Comment: Hmm. Well, I'm unfamiliar with that library, so I'm afraid you'll have to debug it yourself or perhaps post another question now that you have Java code that compiles.